Prevent text selection for embedded PDF in HTML
I have an HTML file with this line:
<object type="application/pdf" data="{{content.field_media_file.0}}#toolbar=0" class="h-[700px] m-auto w-full">{{ content }}</object>

which allows me to render a PDF file.
I would like to prevent text selection from it by the user.
I already tried to apply CSS classes (like "user-select: none") to the object tag and also to parent div but it doesn't work.
Can someone help please?
